# Why the default field id's 'read_only' is True?

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework

when defining a class inherited from ModelSerializer, the field 'id' is serialized by default if u don't add 'read_only=True', but it can't be deserialized by default. I wonder why? the id's 'read_only=True' by default? Could u show me the source code to prove it or tell me where to find it?
Thx for ur helping!

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example, explain what the code does, and in what way, precisely, that is different from what you want it to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is read-only because `id` fields in Django are **auto incremented unique primary keys**, thus they are unchangeable and undeserializable by design. [Here is an example from the DRF docs.](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#inspecting-a-modelserializer)

Comment: Thx very much. But u even don't define `id` fields serializer, how to know `id` field can be serialized or not be deserialized. I saw the docs. and I didn't find it, which just state specifying read only fields not explaining why the `id` is the read only field by default. Maybe I didn't much understand the docs. or source code...Could u show me which source codes show the `id` is read only.Thank u a lot.